# EF Framework converting to EF Core Syntax Error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The following syntax when migrated to EF Core has the following error

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: ij => ij.ImportDefinitionId,
> innerKeySelector: id => id.ImportDefinitionId,
> resultSelector: (ij, id) => new {
> ij = ij,
> id = id
> })
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.id.ImportTypeId,
> innerKeySelector: it => it.ImportTypeId,
> resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier0, it) => new {
> <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier0,
> it = it
> })
> .GroupJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.ij.ImportJobId,
> innerKeySelector: ijp => ijp.ImportJobId,
> resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, ijpGroup) => new {
> <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1,
> ijpGroup = ijpGroup
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

```
   (from ij in ImportJobs
             join id in ImportDefinitions
                 on ij.ImportDefinitionId equals id.ImportDefinitionId
             join it in ImportTypes
                 on id.ImportTypeId equals it.ImportTypeId
             join ijp in ImportJobParameters
                 on ij.ImportJobId equals ijp.ImportJobId into ijpGroup
             where ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
             orderby ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc descending
             select
                 new
                 {
                     ImportDefinition = id,
                     ImportType = it,
                     LastImportJob = ij,
                     LastImportJobParameters = ijpGroup
                 }).ToList()
```

My attempt to change this is as follows

```
         (from ij in ImportJobs
             join id in ImportDefinitions
                 on ij.ImportDefinitionId equals id.ImportDefinitionId
             join it in ImportTypes
                 on id.ImportTypeId equals it.ImportTypeId
             from ijp in ImportJobParameters.Where(ijp => ij.ImportJobId == ijp.ImportJobId).DefaultIfEmpty()                 
             where ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60)
             orderby ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc descending
             select
                 new
                 {
                     ImportDefinition = id,
                     ImportType = it,
                     LastImportJob = ij,
                     LastImportJobParameter = ijp
                 }).ToList()
                 .GroupBy(i => new { i.ImportDefinition, i.ImportType, i.LastImportJob })
               .Select(i => new { i.Key.ImportDefinition, i.Key.ImportType, i.Key.LastImportJob, LastImportJobParameters = i.Select(s => s.LastImportJobParameter) })
```

however this results in a IEnumerable of LastImportJobParameters having 1 item of null where previously there would be 0 items. Just wondering if there is an equivalent EF Core statement otherwise I will filter out once materialised.

** Classes simplified **

```
 public class ImportJob
{
    [Key]
    public int? ImportJobId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public Int16? ImportDefinitionId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ImportDefinition ImportDefinition { get; set; }

    public DateTime? JobQueuedTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<ImportJobParameter> ImportJobParameters { get; set; }
 
}   



public class ImportJobParameter
{
    [Key]
    public int? ImportJobParameterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? ImportJobId { get; set; }

     
    [Required]
    public short? ImportParameterId { get; set; }

     
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }

}   

public class ImportDefinition
{
    [Key]
    public Int16? ImportDefinitionId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ImportType ImportType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public Int16? ImportTypeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    
}

public class ImportType
    {
       [Key]
        public Int16? ImportTypeId
        {
            get; set; 
        }

       
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an EF-to-EF-Core issue. That's a bad EF query to begin with. EF is an ORM, not an ADO.NET replacement. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. Objects should have relations and navigation properties, not JOINs. It's the *ORM*'s job to generate those JOINs from the queries.

Comment: Beyong the unnecessary joins, another bug is `&& (true || ij.JobDeletedTimeUtc == null)`. LINQ is already dynamic. If you don't want to add a condition, don't add it. You can write `if(someParam!=null) { query=qyery.Where(x->x.SomeProp==someParam);}` to append a condition dynamically.

Comment: BTW the *second* query is completely different from the first. You shouldn't have to change the original (apart from fixing the bugs). Which query are you asking about? If it's the first, what do the entities and properties actually look like? There shouldn't be any problem if those were properties mapping to columns. Are there any computed properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The second query is my attempt at changing the query to return the same results as the first query but using a syntax that EF Core was happy with. I will update with entities and properties

Comment: Why change the query in the first place? What is the *exact, full error message*? Post the full text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. You really should fix the query and model though. You're loading entire objects, so none of this code is needed. If `ImportJob` had a `Definition` property and a `Parameters` collection, `ImportDefinition` had an `ImportType`, you could load the `Job` with `context.Jobs.Where(j=>j.JobQueuedTimeUtc >=...)` and access all other objects in your code, through lazy loading. To load everything in advance, `context.Jobs.Include(j=>j.ImportDefinition)...Where(..)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated with Exception. Your right I should update the model but this will have a wider impact than this single query.  At this point my timeframes don't allow me to do this

Comment: It's probably faster to fix the model instead of getting this query to work. This query performs [a GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupjoin) which has no equivalent in SQL. It performs a LEFT JOIN and then combines the right-hand rows into a collection. As the docs say `EF Core doesn't translate GroupJoin.` because that requires loading *all* right-hand rows without filtering, before filtering and grouping on the client

Comment: Perhaps the quickest way is to fix the old query. To do that you'd only have to add the relevant properties. If the tables follow naming conventions, EF Core will map them automatically. If not, you can specify the relations in `OnModelBuilding`. The alternative is what you already tried to do - loading everything in memory then grouping to rebuild the `Parameters` collection. Since you use a LEFT JOIN, a `NULL` param is expected. You'll have to filter this out in `i.Select(s => s.LastImportJobParameter)`. You should call `ToList()` too, to avoid regrouping every time

Comment: Why `[NotMapped]` on the collections? Why not let EF Core do the work for you?

Comment: I added what a proper EF Core query would look like if you only removed the `NotMapped` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use GroupJoin for eager loading, only for LEFT JOIN. EF Core team won't to fix this limitation. Make subquery for retrieveing detail data:

```cs
var query =
    from ij in ImportJobs
    join id in ImportDefinitions
        on ij.ImportDefinitionId equals id.ImportDefinitionId
    join it in ImportTypes
        on id.ImportTypeId equals it.ImportTypeId
    where ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
    orderby ij.JobQueuedTimeUtc descending
    select new
    {
        ImportDefinition = id,
        ImportType = it,
        LastImportJob = ij,
        LastImportJobParameters = ImportJobParameters
            .Where(ijp => ij.ImportJobId == ijp.ImportJobId)
            .ToList()
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The real and probably faster solution is to fix the entity model and eliminate joins. In fact, it looks like all you have to do is remove `[NotMapped]` and write :

```
var flattened=context.Jobs
                     .Where(job=>job.JobQueuedTimeUtc >= date)
                     .Select(job=>new {
                         ImportDefinition = job.ImportDefinition ,
                         ImportType = job.ImportDefinition.ImportType,
                         LastImportJob = job,
                         LastImportJobParameter = job.ImportJobParameters 
                 }).ToList()
```

What the original query does is a [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupjoin), a client-side operation with no equivalent in SQL. EF executes a LEFT JOIN and then regroups the right-hand rows *in memory* to reconstruct the `Parameters` collection. This is an expensive client-side operation that can load far more into memory than programmers realize, especially if they try to filter the right hand objects. EF Core doesn't support this

> GroupJoin doesn't translate to the server in many cases. It requires you to get all of the data from the server to do GroupJoin without a special selector (first query below). But if the selector is limiting data being selected then fetching all of the data from the server may cause performance issues (second query below). That's why EF Core doesn't translate GroupJoin.

If the right-hand was an execution log with eg 10K executions per job, executing a GroupJoin to get the last 10 would result in *all* logs getting loaded and sorted in memory only for 99.9% of them to get rejected.

What the second query does is emulate a GroupJoin, by executing a LEFT JOIN, then grouping the objects in memory. Since this is a LEFT JOIN, nulls are expected on the right hand.

To get the result you want you'll have to filter the parameters, and then convert them to a list or array. Otherwise, every time you try to access `LastImportJobParameters` the LINQ subquery would run again :

```
.Select(i => new { 
        i.Key.ImportDefinition, 
        i.Key.ImportType, 
        i.Key.LastImportJob, 
        LastImportJobParameters = i.Where(s.LastImportJobParameter!=null)
                                   .Select(s => s.LastImportJobParameter)
                                   .ToList() })
```

Comment: Your explanation is great but the accepted answer is the exact solution. Don't know the etiquette of who gets the accepted answer